# WordPress + Relevanssi: Does not get children pages

Tags: wordpress, relevanssi

When I search for a specific title, which is a child page of another, it does not show up and seems not to be in the results query at all. I tried to set parent to none and what do you know, it showed up in the search results.

What is happening and why is Relevanssi doing this? Is it a bug or something I have to configure myself? Been through all the settings and a lot done a lot of Googlin' like an idiot and nothing seems to mention what I'm experiencing..

Edit: typos

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the error and Relevanssi / WordPress had nothing to do with it. Cheers!